# Send message to user if they leave all fields blank when adding data to table; and don't add the data

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

So, I have a table, 2 forms, a sub form, 2 buttons, and a bunch of text boxes. With these I made a button that pops up an "add field" where you type information into text boxes then click add, and it adds it to the table which back on the other subform shows that data; I have that working. I am not sure how to make it not add the data if you leave ALL fields blank though (note; I only want it to be ALL fields, it's okay if they fill out one field and the rest are null). If all fields are null, it sends out a msgbox to the user saying please fill in data into the text boxes.

Another thing I am looking for for a future part of this database is required fields. Where lets say there are 10 text boxes, and before you can add the data into the table through the form you MUST fill out 6 out of 10 of the text boxes (marked with a * which ones are needed) and if you don't, give them an error saying please fill out [text boxes that weren't filled out] and try again. If all of the 6 required fields were filled out, then it can save it to the table even if the other 4 are null or not.

This is the code I have inside of the add button:

```
    Private Sub CustomerAddBtn_Click()

Dim db As Database
Dim rec As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from CustomersT")

rec.AddNew
rec("CustomerName") = Me.CustomerAddSupplierNameTxt
rec("Address") = Me.CustomerAddAddressTxt
rec("City") = Me.CustomerAddCityTxt
rec("ProvinceState") = Me.CustomerAddProvinceStateTxt
rec("PostalZip") = Me.CustomerAddPostalZipTxt
rec("Phone") = Me.CustomerAddPhoneTxt
rec("Fax") = Me.CustomerAddFaxTxt
rec("CustomerSince") = Me.CustomerAddCustomerSinceTxt
rec("Email") = Me.CustomerAddEmailTxt
rec("Notes") = Me.CustomerAddNotesTxT
rec.Update

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

'Send message to user saying it was saved, so they know
Dim intReply As Integer
intReply = MsgBox("Customer has been successfully saved to the database!", vbOKOnly, "Success!")

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a Text Box has a value in it by using `IsNull(Me.TextBoxName)`. So, if you want to test if *all* of the text boxes are empty then you can do something like this

```vbs
If IsNull(Me.CustomerAddSupplierNameTxt) _
        And IsNull(Me.CustomerAddAddressTxt) Then
    MsgBox "Please don't try to enter an empty record."
Else
    MsgBox "(user filled in at least one field)", vbInformation, "Debug Message"
    ' your existing database code here
End If
```

...and just expand the initial `If` statement to include all of the controls you want to check.

Similarly, for required fields, you can check the value of the controls corresponding to those required fields and display a similar message if any of them `IsNull()`.